# If there is honey, the bees will come from nine mountains away

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains

This idiomatic expression implies that, if there is a favorable financial situation ( a situation in which money can be made )  people who would like to use such a situation to their advantage, will cover long distances  to make the most of it. Is there a similar expression in English ?

Comment: The implication of your saying seems to fall somewhere between that of "If you build a better mousetrap, the world will beat a path to your door" and that of "People rob banks because that's where the money is."

Comment: The idiom in the original post doesn`t carry a negative connotation.

Comment: Right—and neither does the mousetrap saying. Arguably, even the origin of the Willie Sutton saying (which occurred in the form of response to a question: "Why do you rob banks?" "Because that's where the money is.") is a simple, nonnegative description of his motivation. Your saying is interesting, in part, because it expresses an ambiguous relationship between bees and honey—the bees are portrayed as being attracted to the hive because of the honey that is already there, not because they want to add honey to it.

Comment: As far as I know, bees eat honey. As to your version,  I don`t think that robbing banks sounds something as non-negative.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be an answer, so I would suggest *go to the ends of the Earth*. `To do all that one can in an attempt to achieve something.`

Comment: Okay, what my original questions conveys, I`ve already explained in the description. The idiom about a better mousetrap doesn`t correspond to the one, mentioned in the headline comment, neither does the expression about the robbing banks.  Here`s the sentence example - more and more emigrants are coming to the USA to make their American dream come true. It`s not surprise.  If there is honey, the bees will come from nine mountains away.

Comment: Do bees steal honey from other colonies? I thought they were attracted to nectar.

Comment: As far as I know, bees do **not** eat honey. Bees eat pollen and nectar and convert it to honey which their larvae eat, but the bees that are able to fly and can thus come from nine mountains away don’t eat honey. So in a purely biological sense, the idiom doesn’t make sense. It’s quite easily understandable, though. Also, @Gio, a ˋbacktickˋ is not the same as an ‘apostrophe’. As you can see from your previous comment, backticks act as start and end ‘tags’ for text highlighted as computer code.

Comment: Does this idiom make sense to you " in a purely biological sense " - a couch potato ? or this one - hit the hay/sack ? What about this one - take the bull by the horns ? Here`s the definition of idiom - a group of words in a fixed order that have a particular meaning that is different from the meanings of each word on its own. Your comment is beside the point.

Comment: @Gio Please remember to ‘at’ the person you’re replying to (by prefixing their name with an @ in your comment), otherwise they’ll probably never see it (unless it’s the person who wrote the question/answer you’re commenting on). I was only replying to your previous comment (“As far as I know, bees eat honey”), not to the question itself. As I said, the idiom is easily understandable, even if it doesn’t actually make sense from a biological perspective, which I think is what confused Sven and Edwin. (‘Hit the hay/sack’ and ‘take the bull by the horns’ do make literal sense; not ‘couch potato’.)

Answer (score 1):

Like bees to a honeypot.
or
Like bees to honey

> like bees to/round a honeypot
>  phrase
>  If something attracts
>   people like bees to a honeypot or like bees round a honeypot, it
>   attracts people in large numbers. 
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/like-bees-to-round-a-honeypot)
>
> honeypot
>  noun
>  1A container for honey. ‘she always had men hovering
>   round her like bees round a honeypot’
>  [Oxford Living
>   Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/honeypot)
>
> phrase
>  like bees/flies around a honeypot
>  surrounding someone or
>   something that is attractive or interesting
>  [Macmillan
>   Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/honeypot)

I haven't found "Like bees to honey" in a dictionary but if you do a search you get quite a few results.

Comment: Using a biologically equally viable, but somewhat less savoury, natural parallel, there’s also _like flies to/on shit_ (or slightly less crudely, _manure_).

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn’t have particularly financial connotations, **”like a bee to honey”** is also used in English. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/like-bees-to-round-a-honeypot) lists it as:

> Like bees to/round a honeypot

Of course, depending on context, and particularly after some banking controversy, the phrase [“like flies to manure”](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+flies+to+manure) (or another, more offensive synonym for “manure”) can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Those who wish to take advantage of a situation [smell blood in the water](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/53/messages/174.html).

This idiom refers to the idea that if another ocean animal is wounded and bleeding, then sharks will be able to smell the blood from miles away, and will swarm upon that animal and possibly create a [feeding frenzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feeding_frenzy).

The idiom does imply not only being attracted to a situation where a gain can be had, i.e. food for a shark or financial benefit for a person, but also that said situation has resulted from someone else's misfortune, i.e. a wounded fish or a gullible mark.  (If you don't want that second aspect, this might not be the phrase you want.)