# Idiom about something that attracts big crowds

Tags: idioms

In Russian language we have an idiom

> слетелись как мухи на говно
>   (fly on it like a fly on sh…)

It’s about something that attracts big crowds, like sales or something. People “fly” there like flies on ****. Well, you get it. So I was wondering if there is some English analogue for this idiom and perhaps something softer and less disgusting.

Comment: Hello. What is it about the Russian language and idioms? They must have an idiom for everything.

Comment: Related: [If there is honey, the bees will come from nine mountains away](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/439486/177853)

Answer (score 2):

In English there is a similar idiom "**like flies to manure**". Apparently use of the word "**sh...**" is frowned upon as slang, but I have heard it said both ways. Yes, the image rendered is disgusting and the idiom has negative connotations.

> You could use something related to bees instead of flies like "**make
>   a beeline**" to something. I have also seen "**like bees to honey**"
>   but it is not referenced as much.
>
> And, I do have to add the idiomatic usages of "**flock**" and "**swarm**". People can
>   and will flock or swarm to an attraction or other events. "*Every tourist season they just **swarm** in to town*".

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+flies+to+manure

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beeline

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flock

> Otherwise it is hard to include the idiomatic property of "**flying**"
>   to something, but perhaps you could use the word "**magnet**" to
>   describe where people would be **forcefully drawn to (fly toward)** a
>   thing or event. Similarly, if something is a "**center of
>   attraction**" it implies powerful drawing properties that could
>   attract a mob. *This also has the **same relationship that "sh..." has to
>   flies.***

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/magnet

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/center+of+attraction

Comment: It's 'Like bees to a honey _pot_'

Comment: Are the passages in quote markup actually quotes from one or two of your sources? If so, which one(s)?

Comment: No.  Just to offset the word or phrase - sometimes.  My eyes are getting old.  Sometimes I use bold, italics, and parentheses too. Sometimes I use all four liberally. I must use quote markup differently from you.  Thanks for the input. I will try to limit use of quote markup - It doesn't mean a literal quote.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is actually a less disgusting, less *colorful* and more literal (actually too literal) idiom: ***crowd-puller***

TFD(idioms):

> **[crowd-puller](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crowd-puller)**
>   Something or someone that is popular and attracts a large audience. Primarily heard in UK, Australia.
>
> The critics are saying that this film is going to be a real
>   crowd-puller, so we should buy our tickets before they sell out!
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved

.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you are looking for is "Draw". This goes to the term 'Drawing flies'. It would not need a qualifier being innately positive.

"The band is very good and has always been a draw wherever they appear."

Using what you have stated the band is also an 'Attraction', successful or not does need a qualifier.

Comment: Thanks for your first post. I would guess that the asker requested a English idiom.  Could you identify what part of this matches that, perhaps with an example that uses the idiom you are identifying.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,  ***drawing card***.

> A feature or event that attracts a large audience.
>
> For example, *This Italian tenor is always a good drawing card*.
>
> Card in this idiom refers to a large poster containing an advertisement for something, often some sort of entertainment. 
> [Late 1800s]

Source: [The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drawing+card)